# Laravel - I get this error when using php artisan tinker - InvalidArgumentException with message 'Incorrectly nested style tag found.'

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and any command I use in the tinker console throws this error : 
**InvalidArgumentException with message 'Incorrectly nested style tag found.'**

I used all the command on my user table that contains an image column.
This is how I solved my problem :

1. I run **composer dump-autoload** command
2. In the User model, I added my image column in the hidden property
   **protected $hidden** = ['image'];

I hope this will help somebody.

Comment: Can you add some more context? Why did you move the attribute name for that column to hidden and how did this help?