# InvalidArgumentException thrown in Laravel 5.2 when using custom primaryKey

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a couple models I added to a laravel project called `Shipment` and `Order`. The data being provided for each of these models consists of a `PackNumber` and an `OrderNumber`, respectively. I would like to use these as my primary keys as the api providing the data ensures these columns will never be null or non-unique. They relate to each other through a third model also provided by the api that has data that references both of these so I don't have to add foreign keys either.

```
class Shipment extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['PackNumber', 'Other', 'Attributes', '...']
    protected $primaryKey = 'PackNumber';
    public $incrementing = false;
}

class Order extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['OrderNumber', 'Other', 'Attributes', '...']
    protected $primaryKey = 'OrderNumber';
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

This seemed to work fine until I went to test things in tinker. I kept getting this error 
`Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException with message 'Incorrectly nested style tag found.'` regardless of which model I was calling.

Via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849012/laravel-i-get-this-error-when-using-php-artisan-tinker-invalidargumentexcept) post I got the idea to add the following to each model:
`protected $hidden = 'id'`

Which made it possible to call on a model and get it's attributes, but when I call on `Order` or `Shipment` I get the following:
[image: SymfonyException]

I'm not clear on what message from the symfony error is other than it seems like it was unable to get the other attributes for the model, but if I call `\App\Order::first()->OrderNumber` I get the OrderNumber back...

I would like to know:

1. Why I'm getting this type of behavior in tinker.
2. How to make it stop.
3. Whether or not this is the correct approach given my goal outlined above.

**Please don't respond with "Use surrogate keys."**

**==========EDIT==========**

attached is the output from var_dump on an instance of one of the models in question. Sensitive data is omitted, only data relevant to the issue. The only thing missing is the other attribute names and their contents. Otherwise this was everything printed on screen. I also added more info on the model definitions above.

[image: vardump1]

[image: vardump2]

[image: vardump3]

Comment: You said the data is provided by an API - do you mean this is not a direct database query where the model is being loaded, rather that you are pulling something from something like a REST API into your model? Also, can you provide an example of your model and sample data entry? It might not be your primarykey causing the issue

Comment: So the data is provided by a third party, but they only allow us so many requests to their server so we have to keep a copy stored on a local database that we manage and update weekly/daily/hourly depending on what table needs to be updated. The API provides all of their entries for one of their given endpoints and we store that response. So when we request Order from the API, we get all Orders and have to store them.

Comment: @Jason far as an example of my model, what are you wanting to see? How my relationships are defined?

Comment: Any hints where the exception is thrown from?

Comment: @miikes is that edit what you were looking for?

Comment: Not really. I meant exception in the tinker (ThrowingCasterException). Can you dump the `Order` entity/model in another way?

Comment: @miikes Well the symfony library can be found here https://github.com/symfony/symfony otherwise I'm not sure why you guys are so eager to see the data. This problem only occurred when i wanted to use those columns as primary keys and I think it's more so a laravel problem. Before that they stored fine as integers on the database. I'll attach an image of another var dump of the objects contents though.